# Keeping the latest date when counting uniques in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
             date                  name
0      20/06/2014            Allan Watt
1      20/06/2014            Cindy Mark 
2      20/06/2014         Luisa Mostert
3      19/06/2014            Allan Watt
```

I would like to end up with the following dataframe that counts the unique values in 'name' and uses the latest date value. For example:

```
      latest_date                  name      count
0      20/06/2014            Allan Watt          2
1      20/06/2014            Cindy Mark          1 
2      20/06/2014         Luisa Mostert          1
```

Currently, I am adding the 'count' column by doing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': df.groupby(['name']).size()}).reset_index()

                   name      count
0            Allan Watt          2
1            Cindy Mark          1 
2         Luisa Mostert          1
```

But this drops the date column off completely. Whereas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': df.groupby(['name', 'date']).size()}).reset_index()
```

Obviously, groups by the date as well to leave me with:

```
      latest_date                  name      count
0      20/06/2014            Allan Watt          1
1      20/06/2014            Cindy Mark          1 
2      20/06/2014         Luisa Mostert          1
3      19/06/2014            Allan Watt          1
```

What is the most optimal approach to achieve my intended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
df['count'] = 1
df = df.groupby('name').agg({'count':sum, 'date':max})
df = df.rename(columns={'date':'latest_date'})
df = df.reset_index()

print df

        name       count latest_date

0     Allan Watt       2  20/06/2014
1     Cindy Mark       1  20/06/2014
2     Luisa Mostert    1  20/06/2014
```